# Serial COM Port issue with Linux hosting server using PHP

Tags: php, linux

As I am not able access the COM port Value with references to Linux Server and windows server.So explain me what all setting need to made with references to Linux & windows Server.As this below code is working properly in localhost

```
<?php


    //You need to set the com with a dos command like like:
    //for windows
    //$output = "mode COM1: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on";
    for linux
   $output = "mode /dev/ttyS1: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on";

    //The next command executes the dos command through php:
    system($output);

    //Create the resource id:
    //for Windows
     $fp = fopen('COM1', 'r+');
    //for Linux
    $fp = fopen('/dev/ttyS1', 'r+');
    if(!$fp)
    {
      echo"Port not accessible";
    }
    else
    {
      echo"Port COM1 opened successfully";
    }

    //Read from port:
    $buffer = fgets($fp);

    echo"Read from buffer: $buffer";

    $file = "output/a.txt";
    file_put_contents($file,$buffer);

    ?>
```

*

Comment: please show the code you are using

Comment: Need more information. Could be a permissions issue. What errors are you getting. Is this cli or web based?

Comment: @JasonK  COM Port access denied / web based

Comment: @cmorrissey just go through with above code

Comment: The user that the web server runs under needs read write access the /dev/ttyS1 . You may also be having problems with your file at the bottom. Best to give it a full path rather than a relative one.

Comment: Comment out the fopen for windows.

Comment: you should use `if(PHP_OS == 'Linux'){` and seperate your calls, in addition you have a line `for linux` that isn't comment out propperly

Comment: @cmorrissey i will use linux sever for clarification i have mentioned with both windows and linux option  Even also giving me com port access denied with                                                                                       $output = "mode /dev/ttyS1: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on";                                                                                 $fp = fopen('/dev/ttyS1', 'r+');

Comment: @JasonK Even after commenting the below file path.I am not able to get com port access .how to provide read and write access with /dev/ttys1

Comment: Your going to have to talk to your system administrator to give the web server user r/w access to the /dev/ttyS1 file.

Comment: @cmorrissey As I m getting following error in linux server -http://i.stack.imgur.com/HAQnH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You never bother checking what OS you're on, and blindly try to open BOTH com ports using the SAME filehandle:

If you're on Windows, then:

```
$fp = fopen('COM1', 'r+');
```

succeeds, and then you immediately do this:

```
$fp = fopen('/dev/ttyS1', 'r+');
```

and KILL the handle you'd just created, because Windows doesn't have `/dev/ttyS1`.

You need conditional code:

```
$path = ($os == 'Linux') ? '/dev/ttyS1', 'COM1';
$fp = fopen($path, 'r+');
```

Comment: when I host this file in Linux server i m getting... Port not accessible

Comment: As I m getting following error in linux server -http://i.stack.imgur.com/HAQnH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Cleand up the code and added error checking.

```
<?php

// Change Parms on Comport: Linux: Windows
$command = (PHP_OS == 'Linux') ? 'mode /dev/ttyS1: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on' : 'mode COM1: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on';

system($command, $retVar);    

if($retVar == '127'){
    echo("Command not found:$command<br>");
    // May want to exit here.
}

//Create the resource id:  Linux: Windows
$path = (PHP_OS == 'Linux') ? '/dev/ttyS1' : 'COM1';
$fp = fopen($path, 'r+');

if(!$fp){ 
  echo"Port not accessible";
  exit();
} else {
  echo"Port COM1 opened successfully";
}

//Read from port:
$buffer = fgets($fp);

echo "<br>Data read from buffer: $buffer";

// Put full path to log in
//$file = "output/a.txt";
//file_put_contents($file,$buffer);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error-                                                                                                      Command not found:mode /dev/ttyS5: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on
Port not accessible

Comment: As the above code  working properly in localhost.As i am not able to get COM Port access only when I host it in Linux server

Comment: As I m getting following error in linux server -http://i.stack.imgur.com/HAQnH.jpg

Comment: As in localhost-http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7vhK.jpg It is working properly

Comment: @Shivarajpatil On the server the command mode is not installed or not in your path. Your going to have to talk to your system administrator to give the web server user r/w access to the /dev/ttyS1 file.

Comment: I need to contact web server  service  provider or the device manufacturer  which i am connecting to get values from COM Port